# Are there native ways to have Android read a string out loud?

Tags: android

I'm working on an accesibility app, I've tried the talkback feature on accessibility settings and I'm wondering if there are any methods to read strings out loud.

I don't want to enable talkback, since it would complicate my app navigation, I just want to read users strings when I consider it useful.

Is it possible? How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, look at the API available here:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html

Comment: thanks, I'm trying to implement it but keep getting error: "Cannot find symbol - symbol : contructor TextToSpeech(..." any ideas why this could be happening? Thanks